Warning: Reading from `value` during component render
This is the usage example for react-native-reanimated-carousel. It shows the warning:

[Reanimated] Reading from value during component render. Please ensure that you do not access the value property or use get method of a shared value while React is rendering a component.

I wonder why the warning happened and if there's any solution for it?
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Carousel from 'react-native-reanimated-carousel';

function Index() {
    const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Carousel
                loop
                width={width}
                height={width / 2}
                autoPlay={true}
                data={[...new Array(6).keys()]}
                scrollAnimationDuration={1000}
                onSnapToItem={(index) => console.log('current index:', index)}
                renderItem={({ index }) => (
                    <View
                        style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 30 }}>
                            {index}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

export default Index;


did you resolve it ?

If you are using shared values from Reanimated, you should use them only within useWindowDimensions.
const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
// ... rest of the code

more in docs
